# What's a good way to prevent web method abuse?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I've been reading a lot recently about using jQuery to call ASP.NET page methods (decorated with the web method attribute) directly, rather than using ASP.NET update panels for my ajax requirements - and for the most part this makes loads of sense.

My question is, what sort of measures should I or can I take to prevent abuse of public facing methods like this. I appreciate that my current methods are essentially no different, but they at least provide some security through obscurity, which is ultimately what I'd like to achieve.

I haven't really been able to find any articles about this, so I assume either it's not viewed as a security issue, or that there isn't a good solution. Either way, for my own understanding, I'd love to hear people's opinion on the matter, as well as any solutions people could propose.

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is much you can do about public facing methods. The important thing to understand here is what do you mean when you say public facing. Is your resource accessible to anybody on the internet or is it accessible only to users of your site who have authenticated themselves? Just because a method is marked as a WebMethod, it does not mean it is accessible to everybody. If you have properly configured authentication and authorization rules in your web.config, you can deny access to anonymous users. I am not sure if that answers your question, but these are some thoughts that come to mind.

Comment: +1: regardless of the mechanism in use, the methods shouldn't be allowed to be called without sometype of authorization.

Comment: When I say public facing, I mean essentially a web method that can be easily identified, and thus called by someone wanting to execute that method. Let me give you an example - say I have a web method to check the validity of an email account and I call it VerifyEmail - the last thing I want is someone using that web method for their own purposes and thrashing my server.

Answer (score 1):

Jason see please

[MSDN Magazine Building A Secure AJAX Service Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793961.aspx)

[MSDN Building Secure Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648643.aspx).

Comment: Hi - I had a read through this, but I am primarily concerned with public methods - as I described in my example in the comment above - if it can be executed through the web browser from the client side, then what methods from this article could I use to prevent or at least, make it more complicated, for someone to use? I guess a lot of the information was beyond my understanding, but surely, if I want to call from the client side, then any sort of token or encryption can be easily viewed and replicated just using Fiddler or something similar? Please correct me if I've totally misunderstood!

Comment: Jason see great article by Dino Esposito in MSDN Magazine (link in my answer). He clearly explains main points of secure problems. About public webmethods (for instance - VerifyEmail) - of course they exist and give some service for anonymous users, but these methods must not enable get access or modify sensitive/secure data!